# PostgreSQL Error - psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, psycopg2, amazon-rds

I have PostgreSQL setup in AWS RDS with database name as `some_files`.
Username of DB is `mobileuser`. It has been given superuser privileges

I want to copy csv file in table called `data_table` on daily basis. So, I wrote a python script (using psycopg2) which would connect to this database and copy it.
I tried using `COPY` command. But received an error

`COPY mobile user.data_table FROM 'csv_location';`

It gave me error that I need to be superuser to perform this action. According to https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=141798

`RDS is a managed service and in order to prevent situations that compromise that service, localhost access is not permitted. The Postgres "COPY" command causes the server itself to read/write files -- potentially directly on the Postgres host. Therefore it is restricted.
An alternative is to use the client based, psql instruction "\copy". Documentation for that command can be found in the Postgres online manual.`

So I tried using `\copy` command using `psql`

```
terminal_command = "psql -h rds_hostname -U mobileuser -w -d some_files -c \copy "+schema_name+"."+table_name+" FROM 'csv_location' DELIMITER '|' CSV HEADER"
subprocess.call(terminal_command,shell=True)
```

I added .pgpass file to my home directory
`*:*:*:*:my_password` with permissions as `600`

Still, it gives me error `psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`
I am running python script using `root` user

Answer (score 0):

While you are ...

> running the python script as `root` user

(why?) the `.pgpass` file has to be in the home directory of `root`, *not* the home directory of your user account.

Comment: Yes, it is in the home directory of the root. I have other dependency commands along with postgresql command which would require root permission. So, I am running it as root user

Comment: @Neil: then I am fresh out of ideas. If you are not confusing servers, users or directories, I don't see what's wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I have been trying onto it for about a day and then posted the question, as even I was not able to understand what's wrong with it.

Comment: Found the issue. In password file, I missed 1 *. So instead of `*:*:*:*:password` , I had `*:*:*:password`

Comment: Actually, stars in question were correct as I did not copy it from my password file. I was taking help from my colleague for the issue and explaining him what `.pgpass` file is and noticed that I have 1 star less. :)